# Recuperar dados firebase - itens de pedido

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Boa tarde

estou tentando listar todos os itens de um pedido em um recycler view, mas a consulta só retorna um valor conforme abaixo :

```
 public void recuperarItemPedido(String idPedido1) {
    databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseDatabase().child("pedidos");
   Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("id").startAt(idPedido1).endAt(idPedido1+"\uf8ff");

      query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                pedidoList.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue(Pedido.class));
            }
            Collections.reverse(pedidoList);
            adapterDetalhes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

em outra tela, esse mesmo código retorna todos os itens que estao dentro do pedido. não sei mais o que pode ser

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.
Tenta instanciar novamente a lista no onDataChange antes de recuperar os itens

```
pedidoList = new ArrayList();
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        pedidoList.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue(Pedido.class));
    }
```

Comment: Boa tarde , tentei isso tambem mas não funcionou...

Comment: Pode ser a classe FirebaseConfig. Mostra o código dela

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia

Consegui resolver alterando o adapter da seguinte forma:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Pedido pedido = pedidoList.get(position);
    List<ItemPedido> itens = new ArrayList<>();
    itens = pedido.getItens();

    String  modelo = "",cor1 = "",cor2= "",cor3= "",cor4= "",valor = "",qtd="",tam = "";
    int numeroItem = 1;

    for ( ItemPedido itemPedido : itens ){
        String modelo1 = itemPedido.getModelo();
        Double preco = itemPedido.getPreco();
        String cor1_1 = itemPedido.getCor1();
        String cor2_2 ="", cor3_3="", cor4_4="";

        String tam1 = itemPedido.getTam();
        int qtd1 = itemPedido.getQuantidade();

        if(itemPedido.getCor2()!=null) {
            cor2_2 = itemPedido.getCor2();
        }if(itemPedido.getCor3()!=null){
            cor3_3 = itemPedido.getCor3();
        }if (itemPedido.getCor4()!=null){
            cor4_4 = itemPedido.getCor4();
        }
        modelo += numeroItem + "\t" + modelo1 +"\n";
        cor1 += "\t"+cor1_1+ "\n";
        cor2 += "\t"+cor2_2+ "\n";
        cor3 += "\t"+cor3_3+ "\n";
        cor4 += "\t"+cor4_4+ "\n";
        qtd += "\t"+qtd1+ "\n";
        tam += "\t"+tam1+ "\n";
        valor +="\t"+preco+ "\n";
        numeroItem++;
    }
    holder.nomeModeloItem.setText(modelo);
    holder.cor1.setText(cor1+cor2+cor3+cor4);
    holder.qtd.setText(qtd);
    holder.tamanho.setText(tam);
    holder.valor.setText(valor);
}
```

Espero que ajude alguém, muito obrigada!